# Two different React Contexts, want to call the other but not re-render component

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I have a problem with my component re-rendering. I have tried to separate the contexts in an App-context and a Player-context so that Player-context can change without updating my Epg-component below that uses the App-context solely.

But I need to set a value inside my Epg-component for the Player-context. So I tried with a callback function called "setPlayerAsset" inside my App.js, and send it through to the Epg-component.

Problem is that when I update the player-context the Epg-component re-renders, claiming that the setPlayerAsset-prop has changed.

Any ideas how this could be fixed?

I have two context files:

**appContext.js**

```
import React, {
  createContext, useMemo, useReducer, useContext,
} from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const AppContext = createContext();

const appReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_SHOW_ERROR_POPUP':
    return {
      ...state,
      showErrorPopup: true,
      errorPopupProps: action.payload,
    };
  default:
    throw new Error(`Unsupported action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  showErrorPopup: false,
};

export function AppProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  const value = useMemo(() => [state, dispatch], [state]);
  return <AppContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
}

export function useAppState() {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAppState must be used within a AppProvider');
  }
  const [state, dispatch] = context;
  const addShowExitModal = () => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SHOW_EXIT_MODAL' });
  
  return {
    state,
    dispatch,
    addShowExitModal,
  };
}
```

**And an playerContext.js**

```
import React, {
  createContext, useMemo, useReducer, useContext,
} from 'react';

const PlayerContext = createContext();

const playerReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_PLAYER_ASSET':
    return {
      ...state,
      playerAsset: action.payload,
    };
  default:
    throw new Error(`Unsupported action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  playerAsset: null,
};

export function PlayerProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(playerReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  const value = useMemo(() => [state, dispatch], [state]);
  return <PlayerContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
}

export function usePlayerState() {
  const context = useContext(PlayerContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAppState must be used within a PlayerProvider');
  }
  const [state, dispatch] = context;

  const addPlayerAsset = (payload) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_PLAYER_ASSET', payload });

  return {
    state,
    dispatch,
    addPlayerAsset,
  };
}
```

**In index.js**

```
import { AppProvider } from './context/appContext';
import { PlayerProvider } from './context/playerContext';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppProvider>
    <PlayerProvider>
      <Router>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <App />
          <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </Router>
    </PlayerProvider>
  </AppProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**And in App.js**

```
import React, {
  useEffect, useState, useCallback, useMemo,
} from 'react';
import { useAppState } from './context/appContext';
import { usePlayerState } from './context/playerContext';


const App = () => {
  const {
    state: {
      showErrorPopup,
    },
    addShowErrorPop,
  } = useAppState();

  const {
    state: {
      playerAsset,
    },
    addPlayerAsset,
  } = usePlayerState();

  const setPlayerAsset = (value) => {
    addPlayerAsset(value);
  };

  return (
      <Epg
        setPlayerAsset={(value) => setPlayerAsset(value)}
      />
    );
  };

export default App;
```

Comment: I did modify my answer, please check again, I can help you further in this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `useCallback` for `setPlayerAsset` to avoid function re-rendering.

```
const setPlayerAsset = useCallback((value) => {
    addPlayerAsset(value);
  }, []);
```

You should modify this as well

```
<Epg
    setPlayerAsset={setPlayerAsset}
/>
```

With this way `setPlayerAsset={(value) => setPlayerAsset(value)}`, it will create a new function instance every time when your component gets re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried that again now but it didn't help. It still says is rendered because of setPlayerAsset.

Comment: `(value) => setPlayerAsset(value)` you need to call `setPlayerAsset` directly like this `setPlayerAsset={setPlayerAsset}`, because you're trying to create a new function instance every time. @TuxedoJoe

Comment: Did you find it useful? @TuxedoJoe